# .NET MVC, Task never goes to status Done

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I try to implement long running operation handling on server without push notification.
My project methods all are Async. All methods out of the web project await with ConfigureAwait(false)
I have library referenced in my web that manages long running operation.
On my initial request I have fire-and-forget for what I think can continue longer:

```
// my fire and forget - the task is not awaited
longRunningOperation.RunAsync();

// add my delay 
var result = await Task.WhenAny(longRunningOperation.Task, Task.Delay(LongRunningConfiguration.Instance.InitialRequestReleaseTime)).ConfigureAwait(false);

// if the task finishes the return on time, otherwise create long running handler
if (result == longRunningOperation.Task)
{
    // it is OK
}
else
{
    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await longRunningOperation.Task;
    });

    monitorTask = new ActiveMonitorTask(longRunningOperation, task)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    };

    _monitorStateSession.Add(monitorTask);
}
```

At the moment I have only one of my operations implemented to support long-running.
Myst of the time tasks for that operation goes to Done status. But from time to time they hang-out in WaitForActivation

Any suggestions how to track the problem or check what can causes it?

Regards,
Boris

Comment: Are you sure it's not just still running, but taking a long time? `WaitForActivation` is a little unfortunately-named, and you can instead usually interpret it as "running".

Comment: Yes, because I can see the finished result. For example file is deleted.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help determine root cause of issue.